# Передача информации между контроллерами

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня в viewControllerB есть форма заполнения (имя, фамилия, отчество итд.)
С помощью делегатов я передаю из viewControllerB во viewControllerA dictionary. Но как заполнить лейблы ячеек из этого дикшинари который приходит из viewControllerB? Ячейки кастомные. 
Пишу на Objective C.

Comment: Ви не знаете как извлечь значения их дикшинери и вставить в нужний Label?

Comment: Приведите хоть какой-нибудь код, чтобы мы смогли ориентироваться и  точно указать на Вашу ошибку.